# Why does Tmux Space leader also make 2 a leader?

Tags: tmux

I have a very simple tmux config file that contains the following:

```
set -g prefix C-Space
```

This works great for using my spacebar as a leader, however it also makes C-2 and C-@ leaders. This is really messing with some of my other commands (in vim specifically).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and tell me what I need to do to get the spacebar to be the leader without magically also accepting 2 and @ as leaders? I've tried to specifically `unbind` C-2 and C-@ to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this ticket discussing this issue: http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/119/

Comment: @northben: Reading the bug description, I'd suggest that Matthew is the originator of the bug report. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @northben and @andreas-wiese mentioned, I did get an answer from [a ticket that I opened](https://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/119/) with tmux.

Here is the response to the question, "Why does this happen?":

> historic reasons. ascii has only 32 ctrl keys so terminals map
>   multiple keys to the same codes xterm may have an option to make them
>   different but you would need to change tmux to recognise the new codes